# How to access list elements obtained from the database and perform nltk methods on them?

Tags: python, sqlite, nltk

```
import sqlite3
import string
import nltk
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')

k=22
c=""
cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT KEYWORDS from Content WHERE ID=?',(k,))
data=cur.fetchone()
cur.execute('SELECT KEYWORDS from CONTENT')
c=cur.fetchall()
print("content keywords are %s" % c)
for i in range(len(c)):
    d = nltk.word_tokenize(c[i])
    for j in range(len(d)):
        print("tokens are %s" % d[j])
```

The above python code giving me the `TypeError: expected string or buffer error` in the line `d = nltk.word_tokenize(c[i])`. I am new to python programming, could anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value `c[i]` of `c` (the result of `cur.fetchall()`) is a one-element `tuple`. You need to use `c[i][0]` instead of `c[i]`.

By the way, avoid `for i in range(len(x)): [...] x[i]` patterns and use `for e in x: [...] e`. With your code, that gives us:

```
import sqlite3
import string
import nltk

conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT KEYWORDS from CONTENT')
c = cur.fetchall()
print("content keywords are %r" % c)
for result in c:
    d = nltk.word_tokenize(result[0])
    for token in d:
        print("tokens are %s" % token)
```